# Display grouped by records in single row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as follows:

```
DeptName     year
------------------
Engineering  2001
Sales        2001
Tool Design  2001
Engineering  2002
Sales        2002
Tool Design  2002
Engineering  2003
Sales        2003
Tool Design  2003
```

I need to group by deptname and display in a single row as shown below:

```
DeptName     year  DeptName year DeptName year
------------------ ----------------------------
Engineering 2001 Sales    2001  Tool Design  2001 
Engineering 2002 Sales    2002  Tool Design  2002 
Engineering 2003 Sales    2003  Tool Design  2003
```

Comment: Where will you be displaying this?  This is typically better done at the presentation layer, in client code.

Comment: The search phrase you're looking for is `sql-server pivot table`.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you actually want to `group by` the `year` field.  Assuming you know all the departments, here's one option using `conditional aggregation` to `pivot` the results:

```
select year, 
      max(case when deptname = 'Engineering' then deptname end) deptname1,
      max(case when deptname = 'Sales' then deptname end) deptname2,
      max(case when deptname = 'Tool Design' then deptname end) deptname3
from yourtable
group by year
```

If you don't know the departments, then you'll need to use `dynamic sql` instead.

Comment: Depending on what he actually needs this for, a `PIVOT` query might be better (and more secure) than dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Zack why did you downvote this?  if the `OP` doesn't know the maximum number of columns, both `conditional aggregation` and `pivot` would require `dynamic sql`...  Otherwise, this is just an alternative to `pivot` which several people have a difficult time understanding...

Comment: You're right about a pivot needing dynamic SQL (if OP doesn't know all the department names). I'd remove the downvote, but it's been more than 10 minutes. Although I wonder if, depending on what the OP actually needs, there's a better solution than hard-coding department names or using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Zack Even with a `pivot`, you have to supply the department names: http://rextester.com/OHB83376 -- if the OP doesn't care which department, then we could use `row_number` and create a list, but at that point, it's a different question.  For future advice, you really shouldn't downvote answers that are legitimate because you prefer a different syntax - I save downvotes for answers that are completely incorrect... As the question is written, this is perhaps the best answer available...